# Resize content of HTML image markup with PHP

Tags: php, html, image, resize, flickr

My HTML page displays an image with the following code (using Flickr)

```
    <?php
    echo '<img src="http://farm' . $photo["farm"] . '.static.flickr.com/' . $photo["server"] . '/' . $photo["id"] . '_' . $photo["secret"] . '.jpg">';
    ?>
```

The thing is that I'd like to resize this image to then display it on the page and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add width and height attributes to your html string.

```
<?php
    echo '<img width='200px' height='200px' src="http://farm' . $photo["farm"] . '.static.flickr.com/' . $photo["server"] . '/' . $photo["id"] . '_' . $photo["secret"] . '.jpg">';
    ?>
```

Comment: IIRC, in some versions of IE resizing like this looks pretty bad due to the algorithm it uses.

Comment: ... are you trying to say you want a javascript library that handles image re-sizing and rendering independently of the browser for minimal quality loss? Ridiculous.

Comment: @Greg: If you don't want the built in browser resize then there is always server side resizing.

Comment: Yes, technically that exists, but in this situation the OP is pulling the picture directly to the client, not the server. It would be costly to load the picture, then send it to the server, then re-size and send it back. If OP wants server-side re-sizing he will have to import the picture using php, instead of hacking it into a dynamic html string.

Comment: @Greg Agnew Thanks for your answer, it fits perfectly my needs. +1 for simple and straightforward code.

Answer (score 6):

Often sites such as flickr allow you to request different sized versions of the image so your best bet is likely to be to request an appropriately sized image.

I'm not sure of the exact details but I looked at http://www.flickr.com/photos/29609591@N08/5735893153/sizes/z/in/photostream/ (a photo I found on the front page of the site) and there are links to different sizes. They seem to be in the same form as yours with the addition of `_x` just before the .jpg (where x is a letter dependant on size).

I couldn't find any documentation on this in a quick search but in this case we had:

```
_s for a square
_t for a thumbnail
_m for a small
(no extension) for a medium 500
_z for a medium 640
_b for a large
_o for original - this url seems to be different from the others
```

I suspect the criteria for these is by fitting to an upper limit of dimensions but I don't know for sure. Trial and error may help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your work. Right now the quality of the pictures is not important for me but as soon as I have some time I'll explore your suggestion.